# Ebay Trading API Get Item Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, ebay-api

I want to made simple post request on Ebay trading api with javascript Ajax. Here is the call format. I got some error on the following request. can anyone tell me the what wrong with the call .

```
const findbtn = document.querySelector(".find-item-btn");

findbtn.addEventListener("click", getData);

function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  };

  const xml =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' +
    "<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>" +
    "<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>" +
    "<ItemID>232789363104</ItemID>" +
    "</GetItemRequest>";

  xhttp.open("POST", "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll", true);

  xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL", "967");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME","6cfe5ebb-73c4-465b-ad24-c4f0aea8de0");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME","RegnantC-SaveWix-PRD-3ef66784f-24730a7");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME","PRD-ef66784f85c1-6c65-4919-bc83-24c6");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "GetItem");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-EBAY-API-SITEID", "0");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Requested-With, Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-EBAY-API-IAF-TOKEN","v^1.1#i^1#f^0#r^0#p^3#I^3#t^H4sIAAAAAAAAAOVYeWwUVRjv9lJEaIigTUWzTiEeOLtz7e7sh"
  );

  xhttp.send(xml);
}
```

and got the following error

`1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll' from origin 'localhost/app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

`2 POST https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll net::ERR_FAILED`

Please help me. is the right format for the ajax request

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's causing the `CORS` error. You can read about it details from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
And if you want to overcome this issue you can enable `CORS` from server. I mean send the request through your server.

Or you can also use `CORS anywhere` header.

`const corsHeader = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";`

then use this `corsHeader` appending with your url like this,

`xhttp.open("POST", corsHeader+"https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll", true);`

It'll send the request and currently it's showing `error: IAF token supplied is invalid`. If you provide proper IAF token then it'll provide you the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to programming in general so this will not be a technical answer in the least, but....  I did get this to eliminate the CORS error.

const corsHeader = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

```
xhttp.open("POST", "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token", true);



xhttp.open("POST", corsHeader, true);
```

I had to go here first and enable temporary access though.
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo

Now when I run this the console is saying:
"This API enables cross-origin requests to anywhere."

If I can figure out how to get any farther I will update this thread.